# C# Determining the Type of the Selected Object in Excel

Tags: c#, excel, dynamic, excel-interop

I'm trying to write a function that returns a string that represents the type of object currently selected in Excel.

Right now, this is what I have:

```
public String GetExcelType(dynamic thing)
{   
    if(thing.GetType().GetProperty("ChartStyle") != null)
    {
        return "[CHART]";
    }
    else if (thing.GetType().GetProperty("Cells") != null)
    {
        return "[TABLE]";
    }

    return "[UNKNOWN]";
}
```

And then later called with:

```
GetExcelType(oExcelApp.ActiveWindow.Selection);
```

Problem is, it returns "[UNKNOWN]" every time.

Further confusing the issue, popping open a debug session we can clearly see that the object has the property in question (in this case "Cells"):

[image]

I pulled the `dynamic.GetType().GetProperty("foo")` bit from several other questions (everyone seems to agree this should work) but it seems to flop, here.  What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Can you have a look / post what is in the list that gets returned if you call thing.GetType().GetProperties() ? AFAIK, there are only 2 way to do this - one is GetType (as you are doing), and the other is trying to access the property, and catching the RuntimeBinderException exception if it fails.

Comment: @Baldrick Maybe I'm doing this wrong, but all I seem to be able to get out of it is `{System.Reflection.PropertyInfo[0]}`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This seems to be what you need:
http://fernandof.wordpress.com/2008/02/05/how-to-check-the-type-of-a-com-object-system__comobject-with-visual-c-net/

Then you could do something like:

```
public String GetExcelType(dynamic thing)
{   
    Type type = GetExcelTypeForComObject(thing)
    if(type == typeof(Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Chart))
    {
        return "[CHART]";
    }
    else if (type == typeof(Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Range))
    {
        return "[TABLE]";
    }

    return "[UNKNOWN]";
}
```

Comment: That's a pretty complex looking function.  Is it really that complicated a process?  (Keeping in mind that I am *totally* naive about everything C#)

Comment: Agreed it is complicated but it should be quite reliable

Comment: This worked after I replaced `interop.Marshal...` with `System.Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal`.  I'm going to spend some time trying to simplify the function for my needs.  I'll post it back in the question when I do (providing a general solution).  Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

You might find this function useful for finding the type of a COM object:

```
Microsoft.VisualBasic.Information.TypeName(oExcelApp.ActiveWindow.Selection)
```

Comment: `Information` doesn't seem to exist for me.  Sorry, I'm a little lost in C# land.  I got sort of thrown at this project with absolutely 0 knowledge of how the whole MS suite works (I'm a Java guy).  Would you mind holding my hand a little?

Comment: @SandyGifford Did you try adding a reference to Microsoft.VisualBasic.dll right click on your references folders and select add reference. Under Assembiles -> Framework select Microsoft.VisualBasic. Now you should be able to call this code.

Comment: @SamPluPlus This would be an excellent solution if this project wasn't already suffering from heavy reference bloat.  It certainly gets a +1 from me, though.